# rigidbody tab not showing in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason, the tab in my unity script for rigid body isn't showing up, and nothing's  working.
using UnityEngine;

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {


    public Rigidbody rb;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start ()
    {
        Rigidbody.AddForce(0, 200, 500);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

This is very confusing for me, any help?

Btw, I get this error:

> "Assets/PlayerMovement.cs(12,9) error CS0120: An object refrence is required for the non-static field, method, or propererty 'Rigidbody.AddForce(float, float, float)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[SerializeField] public Rigidbody rb;
```

Comment: @AeneasTheBadDeveloper No problem. Can you select my answer as right one if that helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo. Right now you are refering to `Rigidbody` insted of the variable name you defined called `rb`.

**So you would need to write this instead:**

```cs
rb.AddForce(0, 200, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you put `RigidBody`, the class, it thinks you are trying to use a static method, which is not what you want to do. `AddForce` is not a static method, you need to call in on the instance of the RigidBody you created i.e. `rb`.

Comment: okay, but the tab defining rigid body isn't showing up in the script properties.